# If two polynomials of the same variable have coefficients that are conjugate of each other, how are their roots related?

Tags: polynomials

If two polynomials of the same variable have coefficients that are conjugate of each other, how are their roots related? In Mathematical language, if $p(x) = c_{n}x^n + c_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \ldots + c_0$ and $q(x) = \overline{c_{n}}x^n + \overline{c_{n-1}}x^{n-1} + \ldots + \overline{c_0}$, how are the roots of $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ related?

I haven't formally studied fundamental theorem of algebra but maybe this is the thing that can come to use? Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: The roots are conjugated.

Comment: but why is that?

Comment: Conjugation of $z^n$ is the same as (conjugation of $z)^n$.

Comment: But the problem is I'm not conjugating the variables but the coefficients...

Comment: My point is that you should compute $q(\overline{z})$ when $p(z) = 0$.

Comment: So you mean $p(x) = 0$ and $q(\overline{x}) = \overline{0} = 0$ will have the same roots, thus the roots of $p$ are just conjugate of roots of $q$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$